# $q.all not waiting for promise array to return/reject

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I'm kind of at a loss here because from what I am reading in the documentation, this should be working properly.  I have a potential of 3 forms that need to be saved.  The 3rd one needs to wait for the first 2 IF they are present since it needs their id's that return.  I have the following set up:

```
var recProm = user.saveData(...).then(function(response)){...}
var stdProm = user.saveData(...).then(function(response)){...}

if(recProm) promise_array.push(recProm);
if(stdProm) promise_array.push(stdProm);

$q.all(promise_array).then(function(response)) {...}
```

However, $q.all never waits for the promise to resolve.  I see the proper promises are in the array, however it simply redirects back to the main page when the code finishes.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here as I am passing an array of promises to $q.all just like the documentation asks for. Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE: The code for saveData is as follows:

```
 this.saveData= function (list, model, successMsg, errorMsg) {
       return $.ajax({
           method: 'POST',
           url: SPUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('" + list + "')/items",
           contentType: "application/json; odata=verbose",
           headers: {
                     "X-RequestDigest": $rootScope.formRequestDigest,                       
                     "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"                        
                    },
           dataType: 'text json',
           data: JSON.stringify(model),
           timeout: 0
        }).then(function (data, request) {
           successMsg !== undefined && successMsg !== null ? alertify.success(successMsg) : null;
           return data.d;
       }, function (error) {
          console.log(error);
          errorMsg ? alertify.error(errorMsg + ' Error: ' + error.name + ' Status: ' + error.status) : null;
          return "error";
     });
};
```

Comment: you can attempt to use `deffered = $q.defer()` and push a deferred promise with `promise_array.push(deffered.promise);` (which is resolved inside `.then` as `deffered.resolve(...);`). _Use one defer per http request_

Comment: so I would do recProm = $q.defer() and then inside of the user.saveData(..).then(function(response){ $q.resolve(recProm);}?

Comment: No need to use `$q.defer()`. The likely cause of your problem is that you are failing to return the chained promise created in the `.then` block. We need to see more code to understand the problem. Otherwise I am voting to close this question as "unclear what you are asking."

Comment: @georgeawg That is what I thought to but it doesn't appear to be working...the user.saveData is an angular service that returns an AJAX call which returns the response on success.  Perhaps I could try putting those calls directly into the $q.all array?

Comment: It’s really hard to answer a question about a bug in code when the *question doesn’t include any of the buggy code.* In order to help fix the problem, answerers are going to have to see what the code is. “It doesn't appear to be working” is not helpful

Comment: @georgeawg I just included the code in the first post. I set a promise by creating a variable to an AJAX call in a service, check to see if it is null, and then add it to an array if it isn't.  It gets to $q.all, I see the correct number of promises in the array(0, 1 or 2), but it never waits for it to resolve, it just kicks it back out to the main page.  It never reaches the point where the AJAX call returns the success/failure point because the code just ends.

Comment: You really MUST show your code for `saveData` or there is no way we can help. It completely unclear what your issue is because you have not provided the relevant code.

Comment: @Pop-A-Stash code added...this is not the issue, which is why I didn't add it. Added it now.

Comment: The promises returned by the jQuery `.ajax` method are not integrated with the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle. Instead, use the AngularJS $http service. In addition jQuery promises are known to have problems. See  [You're Missing the Point of Promises](https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/).

Comment: @georgeawg $.ajax works fine in other areas with $q for me, so I'm pretty sure that isn't it.  I tried it with $.when.apply($, promise_array).then(function(response) to make sure as that is jQuery to jQuery and the same thing is happening.

Answer (score 2):

[The Promise API - Angular 1.x docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api)

> then(successCallback, [errorCallback], [notifyCallback]) – regardless of when the promise was or will be resolved or rejected, *...*
>
> **This method returns a new promise** which is *...*

At line 1-2, you're attaching a .then() method to the promise, effectively *creating a new promise*. I might be wrong, but since there is nothing else "wrong" with the sample, that should be the clue.

Comment: And if the function in the `.then` block **fails to include a [return statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)**, the new promise will immediately resolve with a value of `undefined`.

Comment: @georgeawg that is part of the problem, it isn't even GETTING to the .then part before reloading the page. The .then does have return to it.

Comment: Where is the code showing the reloading of the page? It’s really hard to answer a question about a bug in code when the *question doesn’t include any of the buggy code.*

Comment: @georgeawg its in a form using ng-submit, so I am assuming once it reaches the end of the code, it reloads based on what happens with submit button functionality, maybe I should change that to type="button" and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

OK, the problem was that I needed to change the button type from "submit" to "button" to get it to wait for the promises to resolve.  I'm not sure why this is the case, but as soon as it reached the end of the code with button type "submit" it would reload the page without waiting.  As soon as I changed the button type to "button" the promises worked as intended, using both $q.all and $.when.apply.